# Achartengine does not display the last value on the line

Tags: android, achartengine

hello guys i'm trying to write a simple line graph but it does not render the last value on the lines. I want to show all the values on the linegraph.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wjAP.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vieID.jpg

the code is tried is

```
XYSeriesRenderer rendererLijn0 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererLijn0.setColor(Color.RED);
        rendererLijn0.setChartValuesTextSize(rendererLijn0.getChartValuesTextSize()+20);
        rendererLijn0.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        rendererLijn0.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        rendererLijn0.setFillPoints(true);
        rendererLijn0.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        XYSeriesRenderer rendererLijn1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        rendererLijn1.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        rendererLijn1.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        rendererLijn1.setFillPoints(true);
        rendererLijn1.setDisplayBoundingPoints(true);
        AlleSeries.addSeries(GrafiekDataLijn0);
        AlleSeries.addSeries(GrafiekDataLijn1);
        AlleRenderers.addSeriesRenderer(rendererLijn0);
        AlleRenderers.addSeriesRenderer(rendererLijn1);
        AlleRenderers.setXTitle("Tijden");
        AlleRenderers.setYTitle("Waarde Lijnen");
        AlleRenderers.setYAxisMin(0);
        AlleRenderers.setYAxisMax((hoogste + 20));
        AlleRenderers.setZoomEnabled(true);
        AlleRenderers.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        AlleRenderers.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);
        AlleRenderers.setXAxisMin(0-0.2);
        AlleRenderers.setXAxisMax(GrafiekDataLijn1.getItemCount());
        GraphicalView Grafiek = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(
                getBaseContext(), AlleSeries, AlleRenderers);
        lnGrafiek.addView(Grafiek);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving some padding to your view:

```
Grafiek.setPadding(0,0,20,0);//(left, top, right, bottom);
```